# how to ignore ajaxValidation in delete action in yii2?

Tags: ajax, validation, yii2

I have a form like follow

```
    <?php widgets\Pjax::begin(['id' => 'authors', 'enablePushState' => false]) ?>
    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id' => $model->formName(),'enableAjaxValidation'=>true,'validationUrl'=>\yii\helpers\Url::toRoute(['paper-author/validation']), 'options' => ['data-pjax' => '']]); ?>
    <?php echo $form->field($model, 'FirstName')->textInput()->input('string', ['placeholder' => Yii::t('app', ' FirstName...')])->label(false) ?>
    <?php echo $form->field($model, 'LastName')->textInput()->input('string', ['placeholder' => Yii::t('app', ' LastName...')])->label(false) ?>   
 <?= Html::submitButton('Save', ['class' => 'btn btn-success', 'id' => 'btn1']) ?>
    $widget = Yii::createObject([
                'class' => 'yii\grid\GridView',
                'dataProvider' => $dataprovider,
                'columns' => [
                    'FirstName',
                    'LastName',
                    [
                        'class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',                         
                    ]
                ],
            ]
        );

echo $widget->run();
<?php $form = ActiveForm::end(); ?>
<?php widgets\Pjax::end() ?>
```

and in my model I have some rules:

```
[['FirstName', 'LastName'],'required']
```

my controller:

```
 public function actionValidation()
    {
        $model = new PaperAuthor();
        $requestPost = Yii::$app->request->post();
        if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax && $model->load($requestPost)) {
            Yii::$app->response->format = 'json';
            return ActiveForm::validate($model);
        }
    }

 public function actionDelete($id)
    {
        $this->findModel($id)->delete();

        echo Json::encode([
                'success' => true,
                'messages' => [
                    Yii::t('app', 'Successfully Deleted.')
                ],
            ]);
    }
```

`actionCreate` works well. but I can't delete any recored from gridview, it throws an validation error(required validation).

what can I do?
thanks in advance.

Comment: If you have problems with delete/update action, you should post its code here.

Comment: maybe you can use scenarios

Comment: @rob006 they are just simple delete and update actions. well, for delete action it doen't run anyway, because of fail validation. then in update action I can't save because there is a paperDOI on DB.

Comment: By default you do not have any validation for delete action (what do you want to validate? There is no input except record ID) so there is definitely something unusual in your code.

Comment: @rob006 I've edited my post and give more details of my form(it is a  modal) and actionDelete. I think this problem is related to pjax. all my form(textInputs and gridview) is placed in pjax.am I right?

Comment: Why do you have grid inside of form?

Comment: well, I have to placed grid in form. is it the problem?

Comment: @rob006 because if I had the grid in another place, I couldn't fill firstName and lastName fields by click on update button on grid to updating. for this reason I decided to have grid in same Pjax. but now I have this problem and dont know how to solve it! :-(

Comment: https://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/867/pjax-gridview-refresh-page-after-delete?revision=1